# Cell Level Encryption Vs Column Level Encryption?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

In sql server 2016, what is different between Cell level Encryption and Column level Encryption?. If both are different kindly provide any simple example.

It is not clear to me what is the difference

Comment: based on msdn, they are 2 terms for one concept.

Comment: Why its downvoted?

Comment: Question doesn't need any effort. it is not useful and you can easily find that by referring to documentation.

Comment: @Flicker . thanks i search in google about 2 hours. but i didnt get any clarity. thats i posted here.

Comment: I reverted DV. For conceptual questions about Microsoft products go directly to MSDN. You'll definitely find your answer.

Comment: @Karthikeyan, if my explanation answered your question, you should mark it as accepted so your post does not appear unanswered, and also you give credit to those who took the time to try to help you. More about this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are the same thing.

> This topic describes how to encrypt a column of data by using
>   symmetric encryption in SQL Server 2016 using Transact-SQL. **This is
>   sometimes known as column-level encryption, or cell-level encryption**.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179331.aspx

When considering a row, an encrypted column means an encrypted cell, so that's why you can think of this either way.

BTW, this was introduced in SQL 2005.